# Question about strong and norm convergence.

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, operator-theory

Maybe the answer to this question is so trivial that I can't see it:

Why the strong convergence of operators (on an hilbert space) does not imply the norm convergence?

Many books make this example:

"Consider the bounded operators on $l_2$.
Let $S_n$ be defined by

$S_n(\xi_1,\xi_2,...) = (0,...,0, \xi_{n+1},\xi_{n+2},...)$ (n zeros)

Then $S_n \rightarrow 0$ strongly but not uniformly."

Seeing that it converge in the strong topology is simple but I have some difficulties to see why it does not converge in the uniform topology.
My reasoning was that $S_n \rightarrow 0$ strongly, i.e. $||S_n {\xi} - 0\xi|| \rightarrow 0$ for every $\xi \in l_2$.
Then, if I want to see the convergence in the uniform norm I have to do:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} ||S_n -0|| = \lim_{n \to \infty} sup_{\xi \in l_2} \frac{||S_n {\xi} - 0\xi||}{||\xi||} = \lim_{n \to \infty} sup_{\xi \in l_2} \frac{||S_n {\xi}||}{||\xi||}$

And now i'm stucked here...

Any help is welcome :-)

Comment: I figured it out:

Comment: I figured it out:
If $T_n \rightarrow T$ is a cauchy sequence: for every $\epsilon >0$ it exist a N such that if $m,n > N$ then $||T_n - T_m||<\epsilon$. But it can't be a cauchy sequence because for every n,m ($n \not= m$) we have $||T_n - T_m|| = sup \frac{||(T_n - T_m)x||}{||x||}=1$ if we choose a sequence with nonzero elements just in-between the n and m index. Thus such N doesn't exist and $T_n$ does not converge to $T$ in the uniform topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strong convergence follows indeed from the fact that for all $x\in\ell^2$, $\sum_{j\geqslant n}x_j^2\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Take $v$ the element of $\ell^2$ whose all terms are $0$, except the $n+1$-th which is $1$, we get that $\lVert T_n-T_{n+1}\rVert=1$, hence there cannot be convergence in the operator norm.